# How can i display the all nodes and relationships between two nodes in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Created Year and Month nodes and connected them to Employee node.
Here is the Cypher:

```
MERGE (y:Year {year:toInteger(line.YearofJoining)})
MERGE (m:Month {month:line.MonthNamofJoining)})
MERGE (y)-[:MONTH]->(m)

MERGE (a:Employee {empid:line.EmpID, firstname:line.FirstName, lastname:line.LastName, 
gender:line.Gender})
MERGE (m)-[:EMPLOYEE]->(a)
```

How can I show the nodes and relationship between two nodes? for example, if I select two different employee id, here I want to display what are the relationship between two employees (will two employees as common properties first name, Lastname, month, year etc..)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

With this query you can get all the relationship between two nodes

```
MATCH (n1)-[r]->(n2) 
RETURN {type: type(r), nodes: {n1: n1{.*}, n2: n2{.*}}}

OR

MATCH (n1)-[r]->(n2) 
RETURN {type: type(r), nodes: {n1: collect(distinct n1{.*}), n2: collect(distinct n2{.*})}}
```

Get employees by common properties:

```
MATCH (e:Employee)-[]-(m:Month) 
return {
  month: m.month, // You can replace it with any property you want to group for example "gender: e.gender"
  employees: collect(distinct e{.*})
} as byMonth
```

**EDIT**

> How to know other employees similar to the given Employee​ id. for example, I was working for a company (my age, location, year of joining as data) and I want to know the employees in the company who has similar relationships like same age, year of joining, the month of joining, location etc. w.r.t to me

Below query should work

```
match (employee:Employee) where employee.empid= 1
optional match (employee)-[:EMPLOYEE]-(month:Month{month: 10})-[:EMPLOYEE]-(other:Employee) 
optional match (other) where other.monthOfJoining = employee.monthOfJoining or other.yearOfJoining = employee.yearOfJoining or other.age = employee.age
return employee, other
```

**EDIT 2**

Get count of all common nodes related to two or more nodes

```
MATCH (node1:Employee)-->(r)<--(node2:Employee)

with count(r) as maxCountRelation, node1{.*} as e1, node2{.*} as e2

return {commonRelation: maxCountRelation, employees: collect(distinct e1)+collect(distinct e2)} as result order by result.commonRelation desc limit 1
```

Comment: How can get common properties shared by two desired employees?

Comment: What do you mean by "common properties" ?

Comment: As you mentioned in question. there are only 4 properties for the employee ```empid, firstname, lastname, 
gender```

Comment: for example, Like similar joining year, joining month, similar first name, Lastname, gender for any two employees from the list.  How to employees are related to each other.

Comment: I've updated the answer; let me know for any queries

Comment: thank you. Can output shown in the pictorial graph. now I can see the output on table format

Comment: Output can be shown in pictorial graph but that's only when we don't group the data as far as I know.

Comment: Thank you, How to know other employees similar to the given Employee​ id. for example, I was working for a company (my age, location, year of joining as data) and I want to know the employees in the company who has similar relationships like same age, year of joining, the month of joining, location etc. w.r.t to me. i want to learn more from you, if you don't mind please give your contact info. thanks